# How can I import JSON data from a REST API into BIRT?

Tags: json, rest, birt

I want to use BIRT to generate reports against data that comes from a JSON based REST API. How can I import this data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process for doing this is described at http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/?app=blog&blogid=45&showentry=471, but it turns out that there are a few important steps missing. I'll fill in a few blanks here.

The original instructions describe creating a Scripted Data Source, with an "open" script that makes use of the `com.actuate.json.JSONParser` class. First, it is important to realise that this class is not part of BIRT, and needs to be manually added (along with any dependencies).

The download provided by the original instructions provides the `com.actuate.json.JSONParser` class, but leaves it up to you to source the dependencies. To make things easier I have reimplemented the JSONParser library in Maven, which will then download and package the dependencies for you. It also includes some bug fixes and enhancements like GZIP compression support. You can get the Maven project from https://github.com/mcasperson/birt-jsonparser, and to build the `JSONParser` library and package the dependencies, run the command

```
mvn clean package dependency:copy-dependencies
```

This will result in the **birt-jsonparser-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** file being created in the **target** directory, and all the dependencies copied into the **target\dependency** directory. Copy all of these JAR files into the **{BIRT_INSTALL}/plugins/org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_{BIRT_VIEWER_VERSION}/birt/scriptlib** directory to allow the `JSONParser` class to be accessed from within your BIRT report.

If you want to debug your report, these JAR files will also have to be referenced in the Debug profile.

[image]